# AngularJs Constant value gets changed

Tags: angularjs, constants

I have a module named "app" in which I have defined a constant "PI", later in my controller when i am trying to change the value of constant it gets changed.

I am not able to Understand the purpose of **constant** in AngularJS.

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.constant('PI', 3.14159265359);

app.controller('appCtrl', function(PI) {
    var radius = 4;
    PI=2;
    // calculate area of the circle
    console.log(PI);
    var area = PI * radius * radius; 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually changing the value of the constant. You're changing the value of the lexically bound variable introduced through the dependency injected argument.

Look at the following example using the Javascript `const` keyword.

```
const PI = 3.14;

function area(pi, radius) {
  pi = 2;
  console.log('pi', pi);
  console.log('PI', PI);
  return pi * Math.pow(radius, 2);
}
```

Clearly `pi` will be logged as `2` but we haven't violated the constant nature of `PI`, we've just changed the binding of `pi`.

When you call a function, it introduces new variables into the scope, one for each parameter. You have no control over the binding of these variables—unlike regular variables which can be introduced with `let`, `var` and `const`.

If you inject your constant into another module, you'll see that the value hasn't been changed.

If you want to guarantee that the variable can't be rebound within the scope of the function that introduced it, you can re-introduce it with `const`.

```
app.controller('appCtrl', function(PI) {
  var radius = 4;
  const pi = PI;
  pi = 2;
  // calculate area of the circle
  console.log(pi);
  var area = PI * radius * radius; 
});
```

The purpose of `const` in Angular applications is to make a guarantee that the injected value will be the same, wherever and whenever you inject it.

Answer (score 0):

Though it's a good habit not to change the value of `constant` but the value can be changed. Refer [here](https://gist.github.com/demisx/9605099).

Answer (score 0):

You are **changing the value of Constant** run-time, so it will returning new value at result.

Got to implement is Do not change constant variable.